# Run-time error '70': Permission denied

Tags: ms-office, permission-denied

I have Windows Vista Home Premium and Microsoft Office 2000. 
When I run in Excel (Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0):

```
Sub test()

    SendKeys ""
End Sub
```

I get error message "Run-time error '70': Permission denied".
I am owner those folder and file!
What can I do?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking the Excel icon and selecting "Run as Administrator".